# GIT: Find junction point for patch branch

Tags: git, branch

I'm searching for a way to find the most recent common ancestor commit for 2+ branches, to find the ideal junction point for patch branches.
About "patch branch", I mean this: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180314-00/?p=98235

I've found 2 commands for this:

```
git show-branch --merge-base branch1 branch2 ... branchN
git merge-base --octopus branch1 branch2 ... branchN
```

What is the difference between them:

Docs says:

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show-branch#Documentation/git-show-branch.txt---merge-base

> --merge-base
> Instead of showing the commit list, determine possible merge bases for the specified commits. All merge bases will be contained in all specified commits. This is different from how git-merge-base[1] handles the case of three or more commits.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base#Documentation/git-merge-base.txt---octopus

> --octopus
> Compute the best common ancestors of all supplied commits, in preparation for an n-way merge. This mimics the behavior of git show-branch --merge-base.

Do `git show-branch --merge-base` and `git merge-base --octopus` do exactly the same?
Which one of the commands is safe to find junction point for patch branches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git show-branch --merge-base` is different from `git merge-base` as when using `git show-branch` all merge-bases will be contained in all specified commits.

```
--merge-base
Instead of showing the commit list, determine possible merge bases for the specified 
commits. All merge bases will be contained in all specified commits. This is different 
from how git-merge-base[1] handles the case of three or more commits.
```

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show-branch

The merge base given by vanilla `git merge-base` is not necessarily contained in each of the commit arguments if more than two commits are specified which is different from the `git show-branch` approach. But if `--octopus` is supplied as an argument it indeed mimics the behavior of `git show-branch --merge-base`.

So the two commands should provide the same output.